# Data Grid View when cell is del key is pressed

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a data grid view in when press *delete* key in group type cell then an other form with DGV open.
It then select a value form it but value is changing but the are not showing always empty in it is window application in `C#`

Comment: Not that I understood any of that, but what's the question?

Comment: Also show the relevant code please.

Comment: i have create one dgv in which their is a one column name group type i want when i pressed Del key that cell of column one pop-up is open other form in which i selected a value that value should back to cell where i have press del key my problem i that the value after selection is remain empty

Comment: Without code nobody can help. Please post a bit code to illustrate your problem.